# How to use azure-kusto-python for cross-cluster and cross-database query?

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Currently I can use [azure-kusto-python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-python) to query a single cluster and a single database:

The KQL query:

```
StormEventInfo
      | take 10
      | where environment contains "templ"
      | where userType == "user" or isempty(userType)
```

the python code is as follows:

```py
client = KustoClient(
      KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_application_key_authentication(
            KUSTO_CLUSTER,
            CLIENT_ID,
            CLIENT_SECRET,
            AAD_TENANT_ID
         )
     )
response = client.execute(MY_DB_ID, query)
```

But if the KQL query is as following(it is cross-cluster and databases, this is an aggregate query), how should I code here in python with this sdk?

```
let Cluster = entity_group [
    cluster('https://b1.abc.net/').database('2f43e3ae086a0'), cluster('https://b2.abc.net').database('6a009979fa88')
];
macro-expand Cluster as X (
    X.StormEventInfo
      | take 10
      | where environment contains "templ"
      | where userType == "user" or isempty(userType)
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Where did take `entity_group` & `macro-expand` from?

Comment: The macro-expand operator is currently offered in preview mode. So...

Answer (score 0):

in a cross-cluster or cross-database query, the reference to the remote cluster/database is included in the query text (e.g. `cluster("other_cluster)"` or `database("other_database")`).

there's nothing special you need to configure in the calling code.

for instance, if you have:

1. `tableA` in `databaseA` in `clusterA`
2. `tableB` in `databaseB` in `clusterB`

and you want to union the contents of `1` and `2`, then you could do either of the following:

- send the following query to `clusterA/databaseA`:

  `tableA | union cluster("clusterB").database("databaseB").table("tableB")`
- send the following query to `clusterB/databaseB`:

  `tableB | union cluster("clusterA").database("databaseA").table("tableA")`

reagardless, you do need to make sure that the principal identity used for authentication has read permissions on both the cluster/database the request is being sent to, as well as the other cluster/database that is referenced in the query text.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
But  which cluster should be passed in following method? 
```
KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_application_key_authentication(
             KUSTO_CLUSTER, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, AAD_TENANT_ID)
      )
```

Comment: whichever cluster you want the query to start executing on. execution could later be fanned out to other cluster(s)/database(s) by the cluster execution started on, if the query text includes cross-cluster / cross-database queries

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has been solved. As you said, it is the problem of cluster or database access rights, there is no problem with the query statement.